# python code won't run with .kv file

Tags: python, kivy

I have my python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout



class Premade(BoxLayout):pass

class MyFirstApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Premade()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyFirstApp().run()
```

and my `.kv` file:

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
<Premade>:
    orientation: 'Verticle'
    TextInput:
        id: my_textinput
        font_size: 150
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 200
        text: 'default'
    FloatLayout:
        Scatter:
            Label:
                text: my_textinput.text
                font_size: 150
```

Supposedly, when I run the python code, the `.kv` file would be loaded, but all I get is a black screen. I named my `.kv` file according to the rule, in this case, is `myfirst.kv` and the `.kv` file is also in the same directory as the python module file. I also tried to use the `build` function but that didn't work either. Can anyone help?

Comment: @Moe A answer is correct. In addition, you have an error in your .kv, the line `orientation: 'Verticle'` should be `orientation: 'vertical'`.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `.kv` filename, if you want it to be loaded automatically you should name it `MyFirst.kv` because your app is called `MyFirstApp`. An alternative solution would be to load the file manually as the following:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_file('filename.kv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Has to be called myfirstapp.kv or the same name as the app class